# Makefile targets within conditional statements

Tags: gnu-make

I have makefile structured in the following way.

```
.PHONY: DEPTARG1 DEPTARG2

$(info BUILD_AGAIN is $(BUILD_AGAIN)) 

TARGET: DEPTARG1 DEPTARG2

ifeq ($(BUILD_AGAIN),y)

DEPTARG1:
     @echo Building $@
DEPTARG2:
     @echo Building $@

endif
```

I anticipated this makefile to throw an error if BUILD-AGAIN is n, since it wont have the dependencies available.But It didn't. Any thoughts for it are welcome.

As an additional information **DETARG1** and **DEPTARG2** are **phony targets**.

#### Output when BUILD_AGAIN is y

```
BUILD_AGAIN is y
Building DEPTARG1
Building DEPTARG2
```

#### Output when BUILD_AGAIN is n

```
BUILD_AGAIN is n
make: Nothing to be done for `TARGET'.
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you verify with `$(info build-again is $(BUILD-AGAIN))` just above the rule, and try modifying the commands to confirm that they really are the rules being executed (and not some other rules with the same command)?

Comment: Done some edits in the actual question.It gets reproduced only if DEPTARG1 and DEPTARG2 are phony targets

Comment: Do you declare them as `.PHONY`? Outside the conditional? Then that's the explanation.

Comment: Yes .PHONY is outside the conditional, but can you elaborate please?

Comment: The declaration `.PHONY: DEPTARG1 DEPTARG2` counts as a declaration of `DEPTARG1` and `DEPTARG2`; they are rules without commands. To get the behavior you expect, move it inside the conditional.

Comment: Just as @Beta says. See [Rules without Recipes or Prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets) in the Make manual.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `.PHONY:` declaration inside your conditional would eliminate this error.

That being said you seem to be going through a lot of shenanigans to re-create something that `make` has built in. Writing up or not writing up recipes is no the way to run or not run them. Make has a flag for that, `make -B` will force a rebuild even if the targets are up to date. Replacing the whole setting a `BUILD_AGAIN` variable shenanigans just running with or without that flag should do the trick.